# get count of values associated with key in dict python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

list of dict is like .

```
[{'id': 19, 'success': True, 'title': u'apple'},
 {'id': 19, 'success': False, 'title': u'some other '},
 {'id': 19, 'success': False, 'title': u'dont know'}]
```

I want count of how many dict have `success` as `True`.

I have tried,

```
len(filter(lambda x: x, [i['success'] for i in s]))
```

How can I make it more elegant using pythonic way ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `sum()` to add up your boolean values; `True` is 1 in a numeric context, `False` is 0:

```
sum(d['success'] for d in s)
```

This works because the Python `bool` type is a subclass of `int`, for historic reasons.

If you wanted to make it explicit, you could use a conditional expression, but readability is not improved with that in my opinion:

```
sum(1 if d['success'] else 0 for d in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
len(filter(lambda x:x['success'], s))
```

it can crash if you don't have 'success' in dict

```
len(filter(lambda x:x.get('success',False), s))
```

may do the job

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it elegantly:

```
args = [
    {'id': 19, 'success': True, 'title': u'apple'},
    {'id': 19, 'success': False, 'title': u'some other '},
    {'id': 19, 'success': False, 'title': u'dont know'}
]


count_success = lambda x: 1 if x['success'] else 0

success_list = map(count_success, args)

print(sum(success_list))  # Python 3
print sum(success_list)   # Python 2
```

Displays:

```
1
```

This is as Pythonic as it gets.